# NEST 7 ignore property in nested list

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How Can I ignore the Article.PageRange during mapping of the tested object using the fluent mapping. I'm using NEST 7.

```
    public class Journal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ISSN { get; set; }
        public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    }

    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string PageRange { get; set; }

    }
```

What is the proper syntax to ignore the PageRange from my nested object?

```
            settings.DefaultMappingFor<Journal>(m => m
                .Ignore(p => p.articles.PageRange) <--- 
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Ignore(p => p.Articles.FirstOrDefault().PageRange)
```

should do the job here.

UPDATE:

If the syntax for properties of nested objects is not being supported by `DefaultMappingFor`, I think your option is to create such configuration but for `Article` type

```
.DefaultMappingFor<Article>(m => m.Ignore(i => i.PageRange))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Didn't work I got the following exception
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=ApplyPropertyMappings can only map direct properties
  Source=Nest
  StackTrace:
   at Nest.ConnectionSettingsBase`1.ApplyPropertyMappings[TDocument](IList`1 mappings)
   at Nest.ConnectionSettingsBase`1.DefaultMappingFor[TDocument](Func`2 selector)
   at MetadataService.Search.ESService.ElasticSearch..ctor(ILogger`1 log, IAppSettingsService appSettingsService, IHttpClientService httpClientService) in